# MySQL Replication ignore few columns

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master, master-master-replication

I have setup MySQL replication, is there a way to skip replicating one column or multiple columns from few tables?

Comment: this doesn't make sense in a multi-master replication configuration - are you really using this? What are you trying to achieve here (there might be another way because what you ask isn't easy)? What MySQL versions(s)? What replication type?

Comment: Am creating a slave replication and want few columns which has sensitive information in Slave

Answer (score 0):

Replicate it!  Else you won't be able to failover to a Slave if the Master dies.  Deal with access control in some of the following ways:

- Use `GRANT` to restrict what each user can see.
- Use `VIEWs` to avoid showing the sensitive columns.
- Segregate the sensitive columns into other tables (vertical partitioning), so that the `GRANT` applies to tables instead of columns and `VIEWs` aren't needed.

Comment: On my database, we have an 'image' table containing images/documents along with details about the file type, who uploaded, when it was uploaded and a description of the content and have a similar requirement as OP, where I want the table replicated without the image data. Our database is a replication from a vendor who provides our failover to a slave on their estate. The replication is made for my company is hosted on an Azure VM, so adding the additional volume of the unwanted images/documents has a direct cost (as it will dramatically increase the size of the storage volumes.

Comment: @Sean - Change the schema to have the images in a separate table, then don't replicate that table.  If you want to discuss it further, start your own Question with your specs.

Comment: Indeed, that's the obvious answer, but the schema is fixed by the vendor and as it's their commercial design, it's very unlikely to get changed.